# interrupt a function by other function

Tags: php, function, symfony, loops, for-loop

i have a symfony job that have two function:
launch and stop.
My launch function will import contacts,for example 4 by 4 from database and send to all of them messages.

```
public function launchAction()
{
    $offset = 0;
    $limit = 4;
    $sizeData /= $limit;

    for( $i = 0; $i < $sizeData; $i++)
    {
        $contacts = $repository->getListByLimit($offset, $limit);
        $sender->setContacts($contacts);
        $sender->send();
        $offset += $limit;
    }
}
```

when i launched my launch function it will take for example 20 seconds to import and send the message to all contacts
but if i want to stop it,how can the stop function interrupt the launch function

```
public function stopAction()
{

}
```

Comment: It can't..... especially as each request runs in its own independent thread, and so can't interact with other threads

Comment: @Alaeddine - But stopAction can't run if the launchAction loop is running

Comment: @MarkBaker can i do something in launchAction loop like Evloop class to stop loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **only** purpose is to be able to stop the script, you don't need a full event loop implementation I think. You can listen to a local socket, and break when you receive data.

You could for example run this in `launchAction`

```
public function launchAction()
{
    $offset = 0;
    $limit = 4;
    $sizeData /= $limit;

    // Init IPC connection
    $server = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:1337", $errno, $errorMessage);
    if ($server === false) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");
    }

    for( $i = 0; $i < $sizeData; $i++)
    {
        // Check our socket for data
        $client = @stream_socket_accept($server);
        if ($client) {
            // Read sent data
            $data = fread($client, 1024);

            // Probably break
            if ($data === 'whatever') {
                break;
            }
        }

        $contacts = $repository->getListByLimit($offset, $limit);
        $sender->setContacts($contacts);
        $sender->send();
        $offset += $limit;
    }

    // Close socket after sending all messages
    fclose($client);
}
```

And `stopAction` could hit the socket to terminate the connection like so:

```
public function stopAction()
{
    $socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://127.0.0.1:1337');

    fwrite($socket, 'whatever');

    fclose($socket);
}
```

This should work if you run both functions on the same machine. Also note that PHP can only listen to sockets which are not occupied already. So you might need to change the port number. And in case you start a second process to send messages in parallel, the new one will not be able to bind to the same socket.

A great blogpost explaining some detail is https://www.christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/

If however you wish to **start a long running process**, I suggest you take a look at [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/), which is an excellent event loop implementation that runs on several different setups. It also includes timers, and other useful libs.

You might want to take a look at this blogpost series, to get an idea https://blog.wyrihaximus.net/2015/01/reactphp-introduction/

Comment: Just ask, I can decline later :)

Comment: if i want to relaunch the send again,what can i do to make the launch functiion able to know the last contact id and run again.

Comment: You could save it somewhere, for example a database/table containing job runtime information. This is a simple solution, but anything else would lead you to a long running process. This would mean your script would loop forever, and check regularly if any new data is to be processed. And this is tedious to setup, you would need to learn some more stuff. Even then you'd have to take steps to prevent re-sending after a crash for example.

Answer (score 2):

i will not fully answer but give you two hints how it could work

1:

save a file with process id on launch()

on stop() you could check for existence and kill the process by id

2:

on launch() you can check for a specific db-entry in loop so it breaks if value is present

on stop you set this db entry

Comment: Option 3, open a unix socket and listen for connections which terminate the loop. But in general a form of persistence, e.g. file or database-entry is easier to implement

Comment: @john Smith  can i do something in launchAction like Evloop class to stop loop?

Comment: sorry i have no experience with Evloop